# How to get the id dropdown list on click event

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is my jspPage.

```
<select id="class_Teacher" name="classTeacher" style="height:25px; width: 190px;" onchange="Class(this.id)">
<option id="1">Manager</option>    
<option id="2">Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

And here is javascript

```
 function Class(str)
{
    alert(str);
}
```

i want to get the id of Option on onchange Event. Thanks :)

Comment: <option id="1">Manager</option> this one. m trying to id which is 1

Answer (score 4):

You can do this if you are trying to get the id of the option which has been selected

```
function Class(str)
{
    var select = document.getElementById("class_Teacher");
    var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    alert(option.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your onchange event will look like this. Just remove the `.id` as that will return the id of the select box itself not the option

```
onchange="myFunction(this)"
```

and your javascript function like this, which will alert the ID of the selected option

```
function myFunction(ele){
   alert(ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].id);
}
```

Broken down `ele` represents the select box (a dom object). `.options` accesses the options within the select box. the `[]` brackets are a way of accessing a specific option. Like an array `myArr[1]` etc. and `ele.selectedIndex` returns a number representing the selected option i.e if the first option is chosen - `ele.selectedIndex` will be equivalent to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML (you  should use "value" attribute instead of "id")

```
<select id="class_Teacher" name="classTeacher" style="height:25px; width: 190px;" onchange="onChange()">
<option id="1" value="ID1">Manager</option>    
<option id="2" value="ID2">Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("class_Teacher");
selectElement.onchange=function(){
    alert(selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].id); // id in the html element
    alert(selectElement.selectedIndex);                           // index starting from 0
    alert(selectElement.value);                                   // value of the selected element
};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTUjn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `selsectedIndex` Property of `GetElementByID`

```
<script>
    function val() {
        d = document.getElementById("select_id").selectedIndex;
    
        alert(d);
    }
    </script>
 <select onchange="val()" id="select_id">
```